# generate xml manifest from media specifically audio

Tags: encryption, drm, mpeg-dash, xml-encryption

I  am trying to implement DRM and EME in my my dashjs music streaming app but then I realized that to use dashjs I need to have a manifest xml file to handle segmentation ..etc so does any one know how to generate manifest automatically or even better generate it on the cliemt side when uploading audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it using shaka packager to encrypt and create the xml manifest for me automatically